# Convert binary string to int with same representation

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, int

I have a question, how can I convert in C++ a binary string to an int by keeping the same reprensetation of the number ? For example I want to convert this string "0000" to this int 0000.

When I use this  :

```
string str = "0000" ;
int num = atoi(str.c_str());
cout <<num << endl;
```

I got the number 0 but I want the number 0000.

Comment: An `int` stores a numerical value. `0`, `0000`, `00000000` all have the same numerical value - zero. There ain't no way you can preserve the distinction in an `int` alone. If the distinction matters, keep it as `string`.

Comment: I want to preserve the distinction because I'm working with integer mask I have to do some compaison between some numbers, and I don't know how to work with string mask . Here is my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000038/choose-some-numbers-coding-in-gray-code/48000234?noredirect=1#comment83002344_48000234

Comment: @RedOne The mask `0000` is the same as `0`, there is no difference.

Comment: Well I have to work with string mask then, can you see my other question to understand what I want to achieve and give me a short example to show me how I can work with string mask please ? Here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000038/choose-some-numbers-coding-in-gray-code/48000234?noredirect=1#comment83002344_48000234

Answer (score 0):

You will have add formatting logic using `setfill` manipulator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{

  for(int n = 0; n <= 1000; n = n + 100)
  {
    std::cout << "default: " << std::setw(4) << n << '\t'
      << "setfill('0'): " << std::setfill('0')
      << std::setw(4) << n << '\n';
  }

  return 1;
}
```

This will produce following output:

```
default:    0   setfill('0'): 0000 <-- Desired formatting when value is 0
default: 0099   setfill('0'): 0099
default: 0198   setfill('0'): 0198
default: 0297   setfill('0'): 0297
default: 0396   setfill('0'): 0396
default: 0495   setfill('0'): 0495
default: 0594   setfill('0'): 0594
default: 0693   setfill('0'): 0693
default: 0792   setfill('0'): 0792
default: 0891   setfill('0'): 0891
default: 0990   setfill('0'): 0990
```

Comment: This is a nice idea thank you I will try to start from this.